# Write data to text file in specific format

Tags: r, loops

I have a `.csv` that contains all provinces, districts, and towns of a country. I want to take this data, and process it into a text file with one line for each city and all the information about that city formatted in the particular format below:

```
[1] CountryName<Country~Sovereign State>|[ProvinceName1]<Province~Governorate>|[Districtname1]<District>[Cityname1]<City
[2] CountryName<Country~Sovereign State>|[ProvinceName1]<Province~Governorate>|[Districtname1]<District>[Cityname2]<City
[3] CountryName<Country~Sovereign State>|[ProvinceName1]<Province~Governorate>|[Districtname1]<District>[Cityname3]<City
...
[56] CountryName<Country~Sovereign State>|[ProvinceName2]<Province~Governorate>|[Districtname1]<District>[Cityname1]<City
```

I've tried a for loop with `paste()` and the respective column names and a `write.table` output first, but the columns are not in the order that I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]! What have you tried (show your code!)?

Comment: If I understood correctly you have 3 columns basically containing as text CountryName<Country~Sovereign State>, [ProvinceName1]<Province~Governorate>  and [Districtname1]<District>[Cityname1]<City. You use a | as separator.  So I would get the csv in a data frame then reformat  it with the 3 columns and then save it as csv with the seprator | .

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code as below. You can use `apply` function with `MARGIN = 1` (by row) to  `paste0` your row elements into a line:

```
# data simulation
nms <- c("CountryName", "Country_Sovereign_State", "ProvinceName", "Province_Governorate", "Districtname", "District", "Cityname")
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(1:7, function(x) paste0(nms, x))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# create data character vector
res <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste0(x[1], "<", x[2], ">|[", x[3], "]<", x[4],
                                       ">|[", x[5], "]<", x[6],">[", x[7], "]"))

res
```

Output:

```
[1] "CountryName1<Country_Sovereign_State1>|[ProvinceName1]<Province_Governorate1>|[Districtname1]<District1>[Cityname1]"
[2] "CountryName2<Country_Sovereign_State2>|[ProvinceName2]<Province_Governorate2>|[Districtname2]<District2>[Cityname2]"
[3] "CountryName3<Country_Sovereign_State3>|[ProvinceName3]<Province_Governorate3>|[Districtname3]<District3>[Cityname3]"
```